# How do I configure ufw to only allow outgoing/established connections for a IPv6 network?

Tags: networking, firewall, ipv6, ufw, routing

How do I configure ufw to only allow outgoing/established connections for a IPv6 network?

I am using an old computer with 12.04 installed to create an IPv6 router for my local network. I would like it to act as a firewall as well.

I have a tunnel setup and working with Hurricane Electric and the computer is successfully routing traffic to and from the IPv6 Internet.

I have followed the instructions given at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6#Configure_your_Ubuntu_box_as_a_IPv6_router under the “ufw and Routing” section.

Unfortunately, when I enable ufw, all connectivity is lost.

I'm also not sure what is meant by

> If you only want outgoing connections you also need to change 
>   DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"

Does that mean change it to equal “DROP” or change it to equal something else?

iptables -l
http://ubuntuone.com/0fu17qZ5h3XQp3KP0hQmnf

after.rules
http://ubuntuone.com/2Pc1rzOgIDiDcGSeJ4spmO

after6.rules
http://ubuntuone.com/7ZOeXanT8oinUwu72DKeSz

before.rules
http://ubuntuone.com/520w8EHgyUkDR4tr5rQ3hr

before6.rules
http://ubuntuone.com/5qeoz9EQAesCquMJbItV2a

sysctl.conf
http://ubuntuone.com/2In6k6Abs07LEwe6gC1PgG

ufw.conf
http://ubuntuone.com/4P6RIQqM3zaQ6PbV30AD6T

user.rules
http://ubuntuone.com/3s9vS1oz9sxgOXlxYJD0Da

user6.rules
http://ubuntuone.com/545d5g1G8W2lDe6x5XACzX

Comment: Can you show the ufw config files instead of ghe iptables rules?

Comment: @SanderSteffann Done

Comment: I re-asked this on Server Fault.
http://serverfault.com/questions/497725/configuring-ufw-or-iptables-to-allow-only-outbound-traffic-to-the-internet-from

Answer (score 1):

You need to add rules so that the tunnel traffic is accepted on your external interface. You already allow outbound traffic by default, but because the input default policy is to drop you lose all your tunnel traffic.

Try something like this in user.rules:

```
-A ufw-user-input -p 41 -s <remote tunnel endpoint> -d <your IP address> -j ACCEPT
```

This rule allows protocol-41 (also called 6in4) packets from  to . Protocol-41 is the protocol used for HE (and many other) tunnels. If you don't include this rule then the firewall will drop (default action) these packets, and you will never receive anything over the tunnel.

Comment: here is my edited user.rules http://ubuntuone.com/462PMbBCY5RY8e5iX18plo

Comment: does that look right to you? would you mind explaining in your answer what each part of that line does?

Comment: Looks right if w, x, y and z match your tunnel setup :-)

Comment: So now I can enable the firewall with "ufw enable", and I can ping out to the v6 Internet. However, when I use the IPv6 Portscan feature in the tunnelbroker.net portal and scan the v6 address of an internal Windows box, I get the following. http://ubuntuone.com/1fqRSsvGlq3cAGD0bIpGcA

Comment: I would like to firewall any access from the outside unless it’s a response to an internal request. Is my understanding flawed somewhere?

Comment: The firewall rule I gave you allows the tunnel to work. To filter the *content* of the tunnel you'll have to create IPv6 forwarding rules that decide which traffic gets forwarded over the tunnel.

Comment: What would those rules look like? That's what the question is really about.

Comment: I noticed you started a new question on this. Good :)  The advice there to look at ESTABLISHED state is the right one. Unfortunately I don't have more detailed info for you now (writing on mobile phone)

Comment: That is ONLY needed in your IPv4-router, not in your IPv6-router.
And if it is a simple home router, you can usually set it to forward everything to your IPv6-router (Ubuntu-machine).  On your IPv6-router, you need to set up the IPv6-tunnel. When that works, you set it up as a IPv6-router, add a rule in FORWARD for your LAN and set /etc/sysctrl.conf to forward IPv6.
But new ufw(8) do have support for forward rules (YEAH!!!).